# Use drupal [token] programmatically

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How can I use `[]` tokens in my code?

I've seen `rules` modules allow using these `[]` tokens. They will be rendered or displayed properly even [account:roles] is an array in the email message. It's quite useful when I don't care the presentation as long as I can see the data.

```
[account:uid]
[account:name]
[account:mail]
[account:roles]
[account:status]
```

So if in my code I want to use these token to send an email instead of using the $account object. Is there a function allow me to use these tokens?

Comment: Token use $account object , it able to simplify usage 
You can use `token_replace` and specify entity to use https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21token.inc/function/token_replace/7.x

Answer (score 0):

You can use token replace function.
URL: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21token.inc/function/token_replace/7.x